# How to Subset Dataframe in R bu extracting few columns and How to add column from one dataframe to other based on a simmilar column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two questions. 
Q1: How to subset the Dataframe by extracting some columns from main data frame. For example I have `dfac` as dataframe.

```
ac<-c("a","b","c","d")
dc<-c(1,4,4,3)
bc<-c(1,1,0,0)

dfac<-data.frame(ac,dc,bc)
```

I need a subset df called `subdf` by extracting the column `"ac", and "bc"` from main dataframe `"dfac"`. How i can do that in R? Output shouldbe

```
subdf ac   bc
       a   1
       b   1
       c   0
       d   0

Second Question is How to merge the column "bc"  from dataframe subdf  into dataframe dfac based on value of column "ac".
```

Both Questions are hypothetical to get understanding of the phenomenon that how to subset the dataframe by extracting few columns and how to add a column from one df to other based on some simmilar column in both data frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can do that using dplyr package

> To extract columns from a `data.frame`, you can simply use `select()`
>   from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
subdf <- dfac %>%
  select(ac, bc)

#Output
  ac bc
1  a  1
2  b  1
3  c  0
4  d  0
```

> While to unite back the two `data.frames` by the column `ac`, you can
>   use a `join` function (in this case `left_join`):

```
subdf %>%
  left_join(dfac, by = "ac")

#Output
  ac bc.x dc bc.y
1  a    1  1    1
2  b    1  4    1
3  c    0  4    0
4  d    0  3    0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you it worked. 
Just suppose if my dataframe "subdf" had four columns. say (ac,bc,dd,yy)  But i just want to merge one specific column say "dd" in main data.frame "dfac" based on column "ac" which is common in both. Then how to do that. basically asking about extracting column from one df and merging into other df.

Comment: You're welcome @Aryh! In that case you can first execute a `select` and right after a `left_join`, using the operator `%>%` to concatenate the two commands.

Comment: subdf %>%
  left_join%>%(dfac, by = "ac")  Please correct me.

Comment: In this case it would be: `subdf %>%
  select(dd, bc) %>% left_join(dfac, by = "ac")`

Answer (score 0):

First question:

```
subdf <- dfac[,c(1,3)]
# or:
subdf <- dfac[,-2]
```

Second question:

```
dfac_new <- merge(subdf, dfac, by = "ac")
```